# How do I dynamically decorate a Flask rule?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, decorator

I have a application with a large number of automatically defined rules. I need every rule to check for a `Bearer` token before proceeding.

I have found `app.url_map.iter_rules()` which does let me see all the defined rules. I want a way to redefine every rule to use its current function, but wrap it with the `authenticate_admin` decorator defined below.

```
from flask import Flask
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check that the request has the correct `bearer_token`.
def authenticate_admin(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        bearer_token = vault.get('secret/oauth')['bearer_token']
        expected = ("Bearer " + bearer_token)
        if expected != request.headers.get('Authorization'):
            return jsonify({'error': "Authorization token incorrect"}), 401

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


# .... Define a bunch of routes (Elided) .... 

for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
    # NEXT LINE IS PSEUDOCODE; IT IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
    rule.fx = authenticate_admin(rule.fx)
```

What I want is that after the above for loop executes, all rules will now require you to supply a `Bearer` token.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I just ended up adding following davidism's advice and made `authenticate` a function that is run by all endpoints. I added a whitelist of endpoints that do **NOT** require authentication.

```
from flask import request
import vault

app = Flask(__name__)

# .... Define a bunch of routes (Elided) .... 


WHITELIST_POST = ['/post1', '/post2', '/post3']


WHITELIST_GET = ['/', '/get1', '/get2']


def authenticate():
    if request.method == "GET" and request.url_rule.rule in WHITELIST_GET:
        return
    if request.method == "POST" and request.url_rule.rule in WHITELIST_POST:
        return
    bearer_token = vault.get('secret/oauth')['bearer_token']
    expected = ("Bearer " + bearer_token)
    if expected != request.headers.get('Authorization'):
        abort(401)

app.before_request(authenticate)
```

On a side note, my boss liked this even more. It means that any endpoint we create on the server by default requires a bearer token. In the past we have forgotten to require a bearer token for some endpoints. Now it is opt out instead of opt in.